# Double commutant of compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, compactness

So my question is straightforward. Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a (complex, if necessary) Banach space and $K\colon\mathfrak{X}\to\mathfrak{X}$ a nonzero compact operator. Denote by $\mathcal{C}(K)$ the commutant of $K$—i.e. the algebra of operators that commute with $K$, and $\mathcal{C}^2(K):=\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{C}(K))$.

> For every $T\in \mathcal{C}^2(K)$ that is not a multiple of the identity, is it the case that $\mathcal{C}^2(T)$ also contains a nonzero compact operator?

Comment: $C^2(T)$ contains $T$.

Comment: Yes, but $T$ may not be compact (outside of finite dimensional spaces).

Comment: It's easy to come up with an example of a compact $K$ on a Hilbert space whose double commutant contains an orthogonal projection of infinite dimensional range and kernel.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA. That’s absolutely true. (If you would write it out/expand it into an answer, I would accept).